# Prove that $Z_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}Y_{t_i}(M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})(N_{t_{i+1}}-N_{t_i})$ converges to $\int_{0}^t Y_s\,d[M,N]_s$ in probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

> Let $M,N$ be continuous local martingales, and let $Y$ be a bounded continuous adapted process. Let $t\in \mathbb{R^+},$ and let $(\pi_{t}^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of partition of $[0,t]$ with $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\delta\pi_t^n=0$ where $\delta$ is the mesh of $\pi$. Let 
>   $$
> Z_n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}Y_{t_i}(M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})(N_{t_{i+1}}-N_{t_i}).
> $$
>   Prove that $\left\{Z_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $\int_{0}^t Y_s\,d[M,N]_s$ in probability.

My idea is using the fact 
$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})(N_{t_{i+1}}-N_{t_i}) 
$ converges to $[M,N]_t$ in probability.

Given $\alpha>0$, we consider
$$\begin{multline}
P\Biggl(\left\lvert Z_n-\int_{0}^t Y_s\,d[M,N]_s\right\rvert >\alpha\Biggr) \\
\begin{aligned}&= 
P\Biggl(\left\lvert\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}Y_{t_i}(M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})(N_{t_{i+1}}-N_{t_i})-\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}Y_s\,d[M,N]_s\right\rvert>\alpha\Biggr) \\
&=P\Biggl(\left\lvert\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\left\{Y_{t_i}(M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})(N_{t_{i+1}}-N_{t_i})-\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}Y_s\,d[M,N]_s\right\}\right\rvert>\alpha\Biggr).
\end{aligned}\end{multline}$$
If we can move $Y_{t_i},Y_s$ in front of the sum techniquely, then since $Y$ is bounded, and let $K$ be an upper bound of $Y$. Thus, we have
$$\begin{multline}
P\Biggl(\left\lvert Z_n-\int_{0}^t Y_s\,d[M,N]_s\right\rvert>\alpha\Biggr) \\
\begin{aligned}&\leq
P\Biggl(\left\lvert K\right\rvert\left\lvert\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\left\{(M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})(N_{t_{i+1}}-N_{t_i})-\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}d[M,N]_s\right\}\right\rvert>\alpha\Biggr) \\
&=P\Biggl(\left\lvert\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\left\{(M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})(N_{t_{i+1}}-N_{t_i})-\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}d[M,N]_s\right\}\right\rvert>\frac{\alpha}{K}\Biggr) \\
&=P\Biggl(\left\lvert\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})(N_{t_{i+1}}-N_{t_i})-[M,N]_t\right\rvert>\frac{\alpha}{K}\Biggr).
\end{aligned}\end{multline}$$ 
Then, the last probability converges to $0$ by the fact
$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})(N_{t_{i+1}}-N_{t_i}) 
$ converges to $[M,N]_t$ in probability.

Thus, my problem is how to deal with $Y_{t_j}$ and $Y_s$? Is there any good way to move it out of the sum? or, any other suggestion to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Pei-Lun Tseng : Hint use the fact that the process $Y_t$ is bounded. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge: Can you show me the way to use the fact more precise? I also use the fact that $Y$ is bound (as above), but I can't go further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity of notation I'll consider the case $M=N$; the proof can be easily generalized to the general setting (alternatively, you can use the polarization identity).

Denote by $(\tau_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ a localizing sequence of $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$. Since $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths, we may assume without loss of generality that $|M_{t \wedge \tau_k}| \leq k$ for all $t \geq 0$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (otherwise replace $\tau_k$ by $\tau_k \wedge \inf\{t; |M_t| \geq k\}$)).
Writing

$$\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} Y_s \, d[M]_s = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} Y_{t_i} ([M]_{t_{i+1}}-[M]_{t_i}) + \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} (Y_s-Y_{t_i}) \, d[M]_s$$

and following the reasoning in the first part of your answer, we find

$$\begin{align*} &\quad \mathbb{P} \left( \left| Z_n- \int_0^t Y_s \, d[M]_s \right|> \alpha \right) \\ &\leq \mathbb{P} \left( \left| \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} Y_{t_i} \big( (M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})^2 - ([M]_{t_{i+1}}-[M]_{t_i}) \big) \right| > \frac{\alpha}{2} \right) \\ &\quad + \mathbb{P} \left( \left| \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} (Y_s-Y_{t_i}) \, d[M]_s \right|> \frac{\alpha}{2} \right) \\ &=: I_1 + I_2. \end{align*}$$

Clearly,

$$I_2 \leq \mathbb{P} \left( [M]_t \sup_{|s-r| \leq \delta \pi^n} |Y_r-Y_s| > \frac{\alpha}{2} \right);$$

since the mesh size $\delta \pi^n$ tends to $0$ and $t \mapsto Y_t(\omega)$ is uniformly continuous on compact sets, this shows that $I_2$ converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. It remains to estimate the first term; this is a little bit more tricky. We have

$$\begin{align*} I_1 &\leq \mathbb{P}(\tau_k \leq t) + \mathbb{P} \left( \left| \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} Y_{t_i} \big( (M_{t_{i+1} \wedge \tau_k}-M_{t_i \wedge \tau_k})^2 - ([M]_{t_{i+1} \wedge \tau_k}-[M]_{t_i \wedge \tau_k}) \big) \right| > \frac{\alpha}{2} \right)\\ & =: I_{11} + I_{12}. \tag{1} \end{align*}$$

(Recall that $(\tau_k)_k$ is the localizing sequence.) By Markov's inequality,

$$I_{12} \leq \frac{4}{\alpha^2} \mathbb{E} \left| \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} Y_{t_i} \big( (M_{t_{i+1} \wedge \tau_k}-M_{t_i \wedge \tau_k})^2 - ([M]_{t_{i+1} \wedge \tau_k}-[M]_{t_i \wedge \tau_k}) \big) \right|^2.$$

Using that $(M_{t \wedge \tau_k}^2-[M]_{t \wedge \tau_k})_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale and the tower property of conditional expectation (see the Lemma below), it follows that

$$\begin{align*} I_{12} &\stackrel{\text{Lemma}}{\leq} \frac{4}{\alpha^2} \mathbb{E}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left| Y_{t_i} \big( (M_{t_{i+1} \wedge \tau_k}-M_{t_i \wedge \tau_k})^2 - ([M]_{t_{i+1} \wedge \tau_k}-[M]_{t_i \wedge \tau_k}) \big) \right|^2 \\ &\leq \frac{4C^2}{\alpha^2} \mathbb{E}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left| \big( (M_{t_{i+1} \wedge \tau_k}-M_{t_i \wedge \tau_k})^2 - ([M]_{t_{i+1} \wedge \tau_k}-[M]_{t_i \wedge \tau_k}) \big) \right|^2 \\ &\stackrel{\text{Lemma}}{=} \frac{4 C^2}{\alpha^2} \mathbb{E} \left| \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \big( (M_{t_{i+1} \wedge \tau_k}-M_{t_i \wedge \tau_k})^2 - ([M]_{t_{i+1} \wedge \tau_k}-[M]_{t_i \wedge \tau_k}) \big) \right|^2 \\ &= \frac{4C^2}{\alpha^2} \mathbb{E} \left| \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (M_{t_{i+1} \wedge \tau_k}-M_{t_i \wedge \tau_k})^2 - [M]_{t \wedge \tau_k} \right|^2. \end{align*}$$

Since $(M_{t \wedge \tau_k})_{t \geq 0}$ is a bounded martingale, the expression on the right-hand side converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Letting first $n \to \infty$ and then $k \to \infty$ in $(1)$, we find that $I_2$ converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. This finishes the proof.

> **Lemma** Let $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a square integrable martingale and $0 \leq t_0<\ldots<t_n$. Moreover, let $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a (uniformly) bounded process which is adapted to the canonical filtration of $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$. Then $$\begin{align*} &\quad\mathbb{E} \left| \sum_{i=0}^n Y_{t_i} ((N_{t_{i+1}}-N_{t_i})^2 - ([N]_{t_{i+1}}-[N]_{t_i})) \right|^2 \\ &= \mathbb{E} \sum_{i=0}^n \left| Y_{t_i} ((N_{t_{i+1}}-N_{t_i})^2 - ([N]_{t_{i+1}}-[N]_{t_i})) \right|^2. \end{align*}$$

To prove this, show first that

$$\mathbb{E} \big( (N_t-N_s)^2 - ([N]_t-[N]_s) \mid \mathcal{F}_s \big)=0$$

for all $s \leq t$. Use this to show that in the squared sum

$$\left( \sum_{i=0}^n \dots \right)^2 = \sum_{i} \sum_j \dots$$

all terms with $i \neq j$ vanish.

Comment: Thanks, it's so beautiful proof. I have a question of $I_{1,1}$. Why can we claim that $I_{1,1}=P(\tau_k>t)\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @Pei-LunTseng Since $(\tau_k)_k$ is a localizing sequence, we have $\lim_{k \to \infty} \tau_k = \infty$ almost surely; hence, by the dominated convergence theorem, $\mathbb{P}(\tau_k>t) \xrightarrow[]{k \to \infty} 0$.

Comment: since $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \tau_k=\infty$ a.s, and then $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}1_{(\tau_k>t)}=1$ a.s. Thus, by dominated convergence theorem, we have $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty}P(\tau_k>t)=\int 1_{(\tau_k>t)}dP=\int 1dP=1.$ Am I right? That's why I confused it converges to $0$.

Comment: @Pei-LunTseng Ah, I see, I'm sorry.. actually it was supposed to read $\mathbb{P}(\tau_k \leq t)$. Set $$A:=\left\{ \left| \sum_i Y_{t_i} ((M_{t_{i+1}}-M_{t_i})^2-([M]_{t_{i+1}}-[M]_{t_i})) \right|>\frac{\alpha}{2} \right\}$$ then by the very definition, we have $I_1 = \mathbb{P}(A)$. The idea is now to write $$I_1 = \mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(A \cap \{\tau_k \leq t\}) + \mathbb{P}(A \cap \{\tau_k>t\}) \leq \underbrace{\mathbb{P}(\tau_k \leq t)}_{I_{11}} + \underbrace{\mathbb{P}(A \cap \{\tau_k>t\})}_{\leq I_{12}}.$$

Comment: (To see that the second term is less or equal than $I_{12}$ use that $M_{t_i}(\omega) = M_{t_i \wedge \tau_k}(\omega)$for any $\omega \in \{\tau_k>t\}$ and $t_i \leq t$.)